# Create a variable based on arguemnt passed to a function

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Please take some time to help me with this part(shell scripting) 
I have a code that is

```
helper()
{
  var1="$1"
  #multiple lines of code
  .
  . 
  #so the variable must be created based on what value is passed as an argument.
  $var1_var_name="some string"
  #so I should be able to make a varible abc_var_name in this case

}
helper "abc"
```

So I want to create a variable inside helper function such that that variable name would be

if **helper "abc"** is called then the variable should be **abc_var_name=**"some string"
or if **helper "def"** is called then the variable should be **def_var_name=**"some string"

Comment: What you are asking for is not 100% clear. When calling your function as `helper "abc"` you want to create a new variable named `abc_var_name`? But what value do you want to assign it? Also `"abc"`? If yes you probably want namerefs: `declare -n tmp="$1"_var_name; tmp="$1";`. See `man bash` and search `nameref`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I have included more details in the question

Comment: `$var1_var_name=` does not make sense. You have to remove the `$`.

Comment: An alternative to the solution outlined by RenaudPacalet would be to use an associative array instead. While namerefs work, I find that their use tends to produce code, which is difficult to understand/maintain, until you document exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want namerefs (with a recent enough version of bash):

```sh
$ helper() {
    declare -n tmp="$1"_var_name
    tmp="some string"
  }
$ helper "abc"
$ echo "$abc_var_name"
some string
```

If your version of bash is too old you can also use `read` to set a named variable:

```sh
$ helper() {
    IFS= read -r "$1"_var_name <<< "some string"
  }
$ helper "abc"
$ echo "$abc_var_name"
some string
```

Or `printf`:

```sh
$ helper() {
    printf -v "$1"_var_name '%s' "some string"
  }
$ helper "abc"
$ echo "$abc_var_name"
some string
```

For completeness, as suggested in comments, if you accept to slightly change your approach, associative arrays are another option: all your named variables become elements of associative array `var_name`, the keys of the array are the names you pass to your function, and the values are whatever you want. One important benefit is that you can easily loop over all your variables:

```sh
$ declare -A var_name=()
$ helper() {
    var_name["$1"]="some string"
  }
$ helper "abc"
$ helper "def"
$ for key in "${!var_name[@]}"; do
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$key" "${var_name[$key]}"
  done
def: some string
abc: some string
```